# How should I write $x^*^2$

Tags: symbols, syntax

I want to raise the variable $x^* $ to the second power. Is there a standard way to write this? Perhaps by instead of using $x^* $ using some special star operator I am unaware of.

Comment: $x^{2}$ should work. The `{}` are optional but usually better to put them in.

Comment: I'd say `$(x^{*})^{2}$` to avoid ambiguities

Comment: @egreg I would enforce it if it was me to decide :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are some possibilities:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$x^{*2}\quad x^{*\,2}\quad {x^{*}}^{2}\quad (x^{*})^{2}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd prefer the last one that's less ambiguous.

Comment: Next to that, the third one represents the *logical* structure of the expression and therefore does exactly what DEK considered best for such cases (read the discussion about ${a^b}^c$ vs. $a^{b^c}$ in the TeXbook)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Maybe the third form (from the left) reflects the logical structure, but it's really ugly from a typographical point of view; if I were ordered to suppress the parentheses, I'd opt for the second form.